# Debugging MEF running in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mef

I'm trying to do a proof of concept app for my work using ASP.NET WebForms and the Managed Extensibility Framework.  I've got things up and running(ish), but I can't seem to figure out how to attach the instance of Visual Studio that has the MEF code in it to the instance of Visual Studio that is running the Web App.

How can I attach my MEF code to the running process so that it hits my breakpoints?

Comment: Are you wanting to step through the MEF Source code or code that you've written that is used by MEF?

Comment: Can you share some code as I'm struggling to get MEF work with asp.net forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try opening a code file for your MEF plugin in the instance of Visual Studio that is running the web app.  Put a breakpoint in that file and run the web app.  The breakpoint should be hit.
2. Create a solution which includes both the Web App and your MEF code.  Run and debug as normal.

Comment: We're trying to keep the projects in separate solutions so that they can be managed by different teams.  Is there any way to do this while maintaining two separate solutions?

Comment: @Jeffrey Did you try my first suggestion?  The #1 and #2 were two alternate ways you should be able to do this.

Comment: @Jeffrey - with regards to suggestion 2, a project can be associated with multiple solution files.  You can temporarily combine both projects under a single solution for debugging purposes and still have other solution files for each project separately for the different teams.